# Pandas not finding all values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

When I try looking for all rows with a specific value in a column I don't get all the rows like when I filter for it in excel.
E.g:

Column 1 is of type object and has rows of different numbers mixed with chars sometimes.

```
df[df['column1']== 250] returns 100 results

df[df['column1']=='250'] returns 50 results
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

I tried converting it again to object but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like some values in `column1` are `str` and some are `int`.

Convert all values in one type, like this using [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].astype(str)
```

then do this:

```
df[df['column1']== '250']
```

You should get `150` records back now.

Comment: I can't convert to int because there are some values like 'A100' etc. with chars

Comment: @canoe Then convert all values to `str`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your quick help. This solved this! Although it is a weird error in my opinion for a sophisticated library like pandas.

Comment: Its not a weird error. Pandas maintains `dtypes` of every column. You can't expect to find `int` in a column that has `strings` :)

Comment: Ah yes you're right. It might make more sense to not expect the same result for searching '250' or 250